# Setting repeatCount to 1e100f gives a warning

Tags: ios, xcode, core-animation, caanimation

From [Apple Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Animation_Types_Timing/Articles/Timing.html):

```
Setting the repeatCount to 1e100f will cause the animation to repeat until it is removed from the layer.
```

Here's my code:

```
CABasicAnimation *flicker = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity"];
flicker.repeatCount = 1e100f;
```

Xcode gives a warning:

```
Semantic Issue: Magnitude of floating-point constant too large for type 'float'; maximum is 1.7014116E+38
```

Something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Googol documents don't quite look right.  Submit a bug report and see if Apple knows the right way to infinite loop.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try using HUGE_VALF (which I think is 1e50f, but use the constant) instead. Looking up [repeatCount](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CAMediaTiming_protocol/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfp/CAMediaTiming/repeatCount) tells us:

> Setting this property to HUGE_VALF will cause the animation to repeat forever.

Comment: seems to work, though I'm not going to sit in my chair and wait.

Answer (score 1):

change flicker.repeatCount = 1e100f;
to 
flicker.repeatCount = 1e100;

Comment: gets rid of your warning, it is supposed to be a float value